# Show that $A^2-4A+5I_2=0$ from the following matrix & find $A^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If

$$
    A=\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -1 \\
    2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Show that $A^2-4A+5I_2=0$. Also how do you find $A^4$.

I'm not at all good at proving and I'm totally confused by the $I_2$. What is $I_2$? Could I get a help?

Thanks.

Comment: $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$. I am surprised you haven't seen it. What did you cover so far about matrices?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I learned it a few years back. Forgot some stuffs. But came back to this for an assignment. Got stuck now.

Comment: I see. Perhaps "Cayley-Hamilton" is something you find useful, too - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: Well, you could just compute $A^4$ directly by squaring it twice, but you’re probably meant to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $I_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Now you can verify the identity.
- From $A^2=4A-5I_2$, you can square both sides to evaluate $A^4$.

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, compute the characteristic polynomial and use *Cayley-Hamilton's theorem*.

For the second question, from $A^2-4A+I=0\iff A^2=4A-I$, multiplying by $A$ repeatedly, you deduce
\begin{align}
A^3&=4A^2-A=16A-4I-A=15A-4I\\
A^4&=\cdots\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Is it not [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem)? Not that it matters...

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Some say ‘Cayley’ first, others ‘Hamilton’… I'll fix it, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation for matrix $A$ is $\det(A-tI_2)=0$ gives $t^2-4t+5=0$........(1)

Cayley-Hamilton theorem states that $A$ satisfies (1) i.e. $A^2-4A+5I_2=0$

For second part, write

$A^4=A^2(A^2-4A+5I_2)+4A(A^2-4A+5I_2)+11(A^2-4A+5I_2)+24A-55I_2$

$=24A-55I_2$